# ItemsControl template binding presenting both Main and MainStatic as options

Tags: mvvm-light, itemscontrol

Very confused on what's going on with this. I'm trying to use the EventToCommand to bind an event for a control defined in a DataTemplate of an ItemsControl. When I try to bind in Blend, I'm presented with two options, Main and MainStatic. Why? When I use the EventToCommand to bind to a button defined outside of the ItemsControl, I only see Main and this behavior works correctly. I can't seem to get the Binding to the ItemsControl DataTemplate controls to function and feel it has to do with the Main/MainStatic both being options. Tried the binding using {Binding CellChanged}, {Binding Main.CellChanged}, and {Binding MainStatic.CellChanged} and none of those options function. Event linkage works fine when defined in the view's code behind but not what I want to do so I'm guessing this is a limitation of the MVVM-Light toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if it's a limitation of EventToCommand. When I use the EventToCommand on the ItemsControl directly rather than on a control defined in the DataTemplate of the ItemsControl, the control works fine. Would be nice if it worked, but there's a workaround available. Can't use the TextChanged event but I can accomplish the same by linking to the Keyup event of the ItemsControl.